# Get all products from one category by name in angular

Tags: angular, lms

We are new to angular and building a LMS app and need to get all products from one category by name. We have sample code in backend and angular frontend as below

Backend product.js file connecting to mysql

```
router.get('/category/:catName', (req, res) => { // Sending Page Query Parameter is mandatory 
http://localhost:3636/api/products/category/categoryName?page=1
let page = (req.query.page !== undefined && req.query.page !== 0) ? req.query.page : 1;   // 
check if page query param is defined or not
const limit = (req.query.limit !== undefined && req.query.limit !== 0) ? req.query.limit : 10;   
// set limit of items per page
let startValue;
let endValue;
if (page > 0) {
    startValue = (page * limit) - limit;      // 0, 10, 20, 30
    endValue = page * limit;                  // 10, 20, 30, 40
} else {
    startValue = 0;
    endValue = 10;
}

// Get category title value from param
const cat_title = req.params.catName;

database.table('products as p')
    .join([
        {
            table: "categories as c",
            on: `c.id = p.cat_id WHERE c.title LIKE '%${cat_title}%'`
        }
    ])
    .withFields(['c.title as category',
        'p.title as name',
        'p.price',
        'p.quantity',
        'p.description',
        'p.image',
        'p.id'
    ])
    .slice(startValue, endValue)
    .sort({id: 1})
    .getAll()
    .then(prods => {
        if (prods.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).json({
                count: prods.length,
                products: prods
            });
        } else {
            res.json({message: `No products found matching the category ${cat_title}`});
        }
    }).catch(err => res.json(err));

    });
```

We have sample code in product.service.ts as below

```
getProductsFromCategory(catName: String): Observable<ProductModelServer[]> {
return this.http.get<ProductModelServer[]>(this.url + 'products/category/' + catName);
}
```

We have code in product.model.ts as below

```
export interface ProductModelServer {
id: Number;
name: String;
category: String;
description: String;
image: String;
price: Number;
quantity: Number;
images: String;
}
export interface serverResponse  {
count: number;
products: ProductModelServer[]
};
```

We want to call the getProductsFromCategory in our home.component page and display products from only one category. Would need the code how to get the product display from one category say "Tutorial"

We tried below code but showing error saying not able to find the name Tutorial.

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.productService.getProductsFromCategory(Tutorial).subscribe((prods:ProductModelServer[] ) 
 => {
  this.products = prods.products;
  console.log(this.products);
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You getProductsFromCategory() method accepts String, So update your call like

Pass Tutorial in "".

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.productService.getProductsFromCategory("Tutorial").subscribe((prods:ProductModelServer[] ) 
 => {
  this.products = prods.products;
  console.log(this.products);
 });
 }
```

Comment: Getting below error
ERROR in src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:26:17 - error TS1200: Line terminator not permitted before arrow.

26                 => {
                   ~~
src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:27:40 - error TS2339: Property 'products' does not exist on type 'ProductModelServer[]'.

27                  this.products = prods.products;

Comment: @tskumar kindly share some demo in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Will add to the stackblitz and message here. Thanks